# Explanation of two loops for Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, frequency

Can someone explain how this solution works for an exercise that makes you find the most frequent element in an array, returning the number of times its been counted? I'm new to JS and just need a bit of help with understanding the logic!

```
   function mostFrequentItemCount(array) {
       var freq = 0;
       var mostFreq = 0;

       for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
           for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
               if (array[i] === array[j]) {
                   freq++;
               }
               if (freq >= mostFreq) {
                   mostFreq = freq;
               }
               if (array.length === 0) {
                   return 0;
               }
           }

           freq = 0;
       }

       return mostFreq;
   }

   mostFrequentItemCount([4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3])
```

Comment: The condition in the first `for` loop is wrong

Comment: Do you mean apart from the obvious errors like `i <= array.length` and redunadant code, or with those errors?

Comment: Also, why is `4` the most frequent? There are as many `5`'s as `4`'s.

Comment: complete trainwreck

Comment: @Jamiec because the result seems to be the count of items, not the actual element

Comment: This should only return the count of the most occuring element. Neither the element itself or one of it's indexes

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the error mentioned on comments, the logic that it takes each element of the array in the first loop, and compares it to the other elements placed after (second loop starts at first loop current index), and counts the occurrences.

IMO there must be a more optimized way to do this, because elements are counted many times in situations where it is not relevant (no use to count the 4 again with omitting the first when we meet the second one)

It also doesn't cope with same frequence elements..

Answer (score 1):

if you are really interested in a REAL JS solution:

```js
    var hashMap = {}; // in js any object can be also used as a map
    var array = [4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) // there are better ways of doing this with js es6
    {
        if (!hashMap[array[i]]) hashMap[array[i]] = 0; // if this is the first time of this value in the map - initialize it with zero
    
        hashMap[array[i]]++; // increase the count of each value
    }
    
    for (var value in hashMap)
    {
        console.log(value + ' ' + hashMap[value]); // print each value with the correct amount of instances
    }
```

Comment: Good to have this here, although it's not an answer to the question itself. But a good supplement.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops should be avoided performance-wise, and I'm sure there is a better solution, but still I'd like to give you an understanding of how the provided snippet works:

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(array) {
   // initialize variables
   var freq = 0; // variable that will hold frequency count of the currently checked element
   var mostFreq = 0; // variable that will hold the highest frequency count

   // iterate over all elements of the array
   for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
       // from the current index i, iterate over the array again,
       // so all "following" elements will be checked
       for (var j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
           if (array[i] === array[j]) {
               // if one of the following elements equals
               // the current element of the first for loop,
               // increase frequency count
               freq++;
           }
           // if the frequency of this element is higher then the
           // currently highest frequency, set the mostFreq variable
           // to the frequency of the current element
           if (freq >= mostFreq) {
               mostFreq = freq;
           }
           // if the array has no elements, return 0
           if (array.length === 0) {
               return 0;
           }
       }

       // reset freq to 0 so we can start fresh with the next element
       freq = 0;
   }
   // return the most frequent:
   return mostFreq;
}
```

Please also note that this only works for an array containing only numbers (and will return the frequency, not the most frequent number, as mentioned in the comments). Adaptions would have to be made to to return the actual element when strings or objects are to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution:

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(array) {
   return array.reduce(function(p,c){
         if(p[c] === undefined)
            p[c] = 0;
         p[c]++;
         if(p.mostFrequent == undefined || p[c]>p[p.mostFrequent])
            p.mostFrequent = c;
         return p;
   },{}).mostFrequent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function does not find the most frequent element, only the amount of times the most frequent element showed up.

It works by counting the amount of times each element show up.

The outer for loop makes sure you check every element in the array. The inner loop counts how many times this element showed up. Every time the inner loop finds an element more frequent than the previous elements, it updates `mostFreq`.

Its worth noticing that this code can be optimized by using an auxiliar array, that counts how many times each element showed up. Also, as stated in comments, the loop conditions are incorrect, since array.length returns the first empty position in the array.